# Writing to a new Excel column based on other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel table like this shown below. There are some empty cells under each header F1, F2, F3, F4, and F5.

```
Path       F1   F2  F3  F4  F5  NewPath
image1.png  1   0   -1      1   
image2.png  1   -1          1   
image3.png  1   0   1   -1  1   
image4.png  1   0   0   1       
image5.png  1   1   1   -1      
image6.png      1           -1  
image7.png      -1  1   1   0   
image8.png      0       1   1
```

I have to write the values in column 1 (under the header "Path") to the column (under the header "NewPath") only if the following conditions are satisfied:

**There should be a 1 in F3 and not any other value, i.e., 0, -1, or empty field.

There should not be a 1 or -1  in any of F1, F2, F4, and F5.**

Comment: I don't understand. Given your sample data I don't see any row that satisfies your requirements. (`1` in F3 with a `1` or `-1` in F1, f2, F4, or F5). I don't understand what a "Path" value is or how you would write one. What are you asking?

Comment: @JNevill I edited my question to convey clarity. Thanks.

Comment: Still no row of the example data would meet given criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever cell you need to write to, you can use an if/and statement. Assuming that the word "Path" is in cell "A1" this might look like the following:

```
=if(and(d2=1,b2<>1,b2<>-1,c2<>1,c2<>-1,e2<>1,e2<>-1,f2<>1,f2<>-1),a2,"Incorrect Value Found")
```

Then, just copy down the formulas. I put in "Incorrect Value Found" for those instances that do not satisfy your conditions, but this could be anything. If you need to cut those out after the fact, you could do so by filtering, ordering them to the bottom, or a slicer on a pivot table.

Hope this helps. Let me know if I missed the mark on my understanding of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like
`=IF(AND($D2=1,COUNTIF($b2:$f2,"<>0")>=1),$A2,"")`

Work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is **no match** in the input data based on your requirements. I modified (**highlighted** cells, see screenshot below) the input data so we can have at least one match for testing purpose.

In cell `G2` put the following formula:

```
=LET(f3Cond, $D$2:$D$9=1, f1f2f4f5Cond, 
 MMULT(ABS(CHOOSECOLS(B2:F9,{1,2,4,5})),{1;1;1;1})=0,
 allCond, IFERROR(XMATCH(f3Cond * f1f2f4f5Cond,1),""), 
 MAP(allCond, A2:A9, LAMBDA(a,b,IF(a=1, b, "")))
)
```

and here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

### Explanation

We use `LET` to define intermediate calculations. The variable `f1f2f4f5Cond` represents the condition for **F1**, **F2**,**F4** and **F5** columns.

```
MMULT(ABS(CHOOSECOLS(B2:F9,{1,2,4,5})),{1;1;1;1})=0
```

We use `CHOOSECOLS` to select the specific columns from range `B2:F9` we need to evaluate the conditions. We need to exclude `1`, `-1`, so we use `ABS` to ensure `MMULT` returns the sum of all `1`'s per row. We can use `MMULT` for this purpose because the only values we have are `0`,`1` and empty. All the conditions are valid if the total number of `1`'s is `0`.

**Note**: As an alternative you can replace the `MMULT` calculation with the following:

```
= BYROW(ABS(CHOOSECOLS(B2:F9,{1,2,4,5})), 
  LAMBDA(a, SUM(a)=0))
```

We use `XMATCH` to identify the rows where all the conditions are met.

```
IFERROR(XMATCH(f3Cond * f1f2f4f5Cond,1),"")
```

`#N/A` values are converted to empty string. The array `allCond` has `1` only where all conditions are met, otherwise empty string.

Finally we use a `MAP` function to populate the **Path** column value from the rows that matches the conditions, otherwise an empty string.